# Powershell Add Output of Select to Variable

Tags: powershell, variables, syntax, output, pipeline

I'd like to store the output of the command Select in a variable. Here's the original code:

```
# OUs to search for servers
"OU=Domain Controllers,$mydomain", "OU=Server,OU=Berlin,$mydomain" | 
# For each OU get Windows Server
ForEach { Get-ADComputer -Filter { OperatingSystem -Like '*Windows Server*' } -Properties OperatingSystem -SearchBase $_ } | 
Select -Exp Name | Add-Content C:\serverfile.txt
```

In the last line I'd like to change Add-Content to a command that adds the output to a variable $Servers. However I can't get the syntax right. I tried:

```
| Add-Content $Servers

| $Servers

"> $Servers"

$Servers += Select -Exp Name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and array ($Servers for example) then add each result into it:

```
$Servers = @()
"OU=Domain Controllers,$mydomain", "OU=Server,OU=Berlin,$mydomain" | 
# For each OU get Windows Server
ForEach { $Servers += Get-ADComputer -Filter { OperatingSystem -Like '*Windows Server*' } -Properties OperatingSystem -SearchBase $_ | Select -ExpandProperty Name}
```

Comment: Also, you can replace `$Servers +=` with `[array]$Servers +=` and avoid having to initialise the array (i.e. no need for `$Servers = @()`.)

Answer (score 1):

- `Add-Content $Servers` - `Add-content` would expect that `$servers` is a file path. This is not what you want. See more from [Add-Content](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849859.aspx).
- `| $Servers` - `$servers` is not a function, cmdlet, alias or command that accepts pipeline input. This is not what you want. Here is a video that can be a start for [understanding the pipeline](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/powershell-understanding-the-pipeline-get-your-one-liners-to-work.aspx). Not the best example but it is a start.
- `"> $Servers"` - Redirection is also supposed to be used for file paths (for the most part.). `$servers` is not a file path. This is not what you want. See more from [about_redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx).

You can just assign the output from the pipeline to a variable directly. This is what you could do. Other options do exist as well like building the array inside the loop. That is unnecessary.

```
$servers = "OU=Domain Controllers,$mydomain", "OU=Server,OU=Berlin,$mydomain" | ForEach-Object { 
    Get-ADComputer -Filter { OperatingSystem -Like '*Windows Server*' } -Properties OperatingSystem -SearchBase $_ } | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Or if you need to do both output to file and variable you can use [Tee-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx)

```
"OU=Domain Controllers,$mydomain", "OU=Server,OU=Berlin,$mydomain" | ForEach-Object { 
    Get-ADComputer -Filter { OperatingSystem -Like '*Windows Server*' } -Properties OperatingSystem -SearchBase $_ } | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Tee-Object -Variable servers | Add-Content "C:\serverfile.txt"
```

In both cases `$servers` will contain the output.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. I always looked for a way to put the variable after the pipeline, but I know now that this was the wrong approach. I used the solution of @gmsoulman, it seemed to fit my script best.

Comment: @Peter If you start doing 1000's of computer be careful as that is a memory intensive operation. Building an array like that make PowerShell build a new array and then append the new object. Glad you found a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will be doing it for only about 100 servers. And I eventually used the other solution.